# display javascript code in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

**On IE Quirks mode**, I want to use following code to display some javascript functions on a html page:

```
document.write('<pre>' + someFunction + '</pre>');
```

But if a function's source contains '<', only source code ahead of '<' will be displayed.

for example :

```
function a(j){
   var i = 0;
   if(i<j){
       alert(j + ' is greater than zero');
   }
}
```

will be displayed as :

```
function a(j){
       var i = 0;
       if(i
```

how to make it display the full source code of a function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of using that '<' or '>' symbols you can use their html rxpressions.

Eg `&lt;` instead of < and `&gt;` instead of  > .

This will solve your problem . Try this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `<` symbol by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`.

Answer (score 1):

Use .replace(), e.g.

```
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    alert("bar");
  }
}
document.write("<pre>"+foo.toString().replace("<","&lt;")+"</pre>");
```

outputs:

```
function foo(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        alert("bar");
    }
}
```